# Options for loading a bunch of disparate data sets into a 'target' schema

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, etl, azure-data-lake

## Background

- 5-10 data sources
- Various formats (csv, psv, xml)
- Different update schedules (weekly, monthly, quarterly)

## Requirements

- Only interested in *some* of the fields from each data source
- Want to build a *model* from the various sources, into a single database (SQL Server)

## Current platform/skillset

- Azure
- SQL Server

## Considerations

- Minimal code. Hopefully i can do this all via a UI/drag-drop interface.
- Automation. Hoping i can drop the files onto a server when it needs to be updated, then "things" kick off (Azure Functions blob/FTP trigger?)

## Questions

I haven't done much in the ETL space, but my initial thoughts point to something like [SQL Server Integration Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services), mainly because that's the only thing i can ever had experience in, ETL-wise.

Now that we have things like [Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/), SQL Data Warehouse, etc, would that be a better solution? Obviously the answer is "it depends", so what questions do i need to go about asking myself in order to clarify that? Can someone please point me to a good article to get started in this space?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The main question is where do you want to stage the data.

Many people are talking about **Azure Data Lake** as a staging area.  There are pros and cons to this solution.

The pros are Azure Active Directory Service can be federated with your on premise forest.  Once that is done, regular Access Control List can be used to restrict access.

The cons are the fact that you are using premium storage (SSD) which can cost a-lot of money for a small to medium size company.

On the other hand, **Azure Blob Storage** has been around for a long time.  One of the pros is the cost of this storage.  A shared access signature (SAS) can be used to let anyone access to the account.

The cons is that the SAS is the key to the whole kingdom.  Unlike ADLS, you can not assign privledges at the file.

If you like SQL Server OpenRowSet or Bulk Insert, you are in for a treat.  Support for those functions were added earlier this year.

Check out my [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5064/bulk-insert-data-into-a-azure-sql-database-with-powershell/) on MS SQL TIPS for the details.

As for scheduling, you can use a very simple Power Shell script in Azure Automation to create a hands off process.

Azure Data Factory might be able to do some of these tasks; However, you adding a-lot more complexity than a simple T-SQL statement to load data into a table.

Last but not least, learn to love PowerShell.  You can pretty much do any type of file processing with that language and the right .NET components.

Happy coding.

John Miner

The Crafty DBA

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer. We are a small team rigt now, so yes Azure Data Lake would be pretty much out of the question. Just so i can understand your answer, are you suggesting we don't do any ETL-style work (e.g with SSIS, Azure Data Factory), but instead write SQL code to import each data source? We have around 5-10 sources to deal with, all in different formats. They will be 'downloaded' from the web manually, and need to be placed somewhere for importing. So we can definetely use blobs as the staging area.

Comment: Why manually download anything?  Look at Azure Automation and PowerShell.  Many things can be automated with PowerShell and scheduled with Azure Automation.  You can call dynamic SQL from the PowerShell program to use BULK INSERT or OPENROWSET.  Yes, you can use a ETL tool like SSIS.  But I would suggest using it with SQL Server (IAAS).  Data factory integration with SSIS was just released and has to be proven (bug free).  Please up tick ...

Comment: Because the 'place' to get the files aren't constant. E.g there's no API. It's govt data that gets updated via a new page. So it can't be automated. I'm not really concerned with the data sourcing part of it, more how to get it from the raw data format into a better format. Noted RE Data Factory. I'll have to do some research. I think what im trying to achieve here is less code to get the data into the format i want, which i was i kept looking at ETL. Answer upticked.